# Orientdb query - Find all the connection leading to a vertex

Tags: orientdb

I have the following use-case in orientdb.

```
(V= Vertex, E=Edge)
FacebookAccount(V) -> OwnedBy(E) ->Human(V) 
TwitterAccount(V) -> OwnedBy(E) ->Human(V) 

TwitterAccount(V) OR FacebookAccount(V) -> FriendOf(E) -> TwitterAccount(V) OR FacebookAccount(V)
```

I want to see how all the Humans are connected to a specific Human. 
1. I dont want to see `FacebookAccount` or `TwitterAccount` that are NOT owned by a Human, this should be hidden: `15:2`.
2. I dont want to see `FacebookAccount` or `TwitterAccount` that are `OwenedBy` a `Human` and not leading to another `Human`. these should be hidden: `17:0, 18:0, 17:1`

I have the following query:

```
traverse in("FriendOf"),out("FriendOf"), in("OwnedBy"),out("OwnedBy")  from #19:0 while $depth <= 10
```

The problem is that this query returns back Accounts that are not owned by anyone, I want to remove that.

[image]

Here is the full script to create the database with all the data:

```
create class FacebookAccount IF NOT EXISTS extends V;
create class TwitterAccount IF NOT EXISTS extends V;
create class Human IF NOT EXISTS extends V;
create class OwnedBy IF NOT EXISTS extends E;
create class FriendOf IF NOT EXISTS extends E;

/* A */
create VERTEX FacebookAccount set user='A_FB';
create VERTEX TwitterAccount set user='A_TW';
create VERTEX Human set person='A';
CREATE EDGE OwnedBy FROM (Select from FacebookAccount where user='A_FB') TO (Select from Human where person='A');
CREATE EDGE OwnedBy FROM (Select from TwitterAccount where user='A_TW') TO (Select from Human where person='A');

/* B */
create VERTEX FacebookAccount set user='B_FB';
create VERTEX TwitterAccount set user='B_TW';
create VERTEX Human set person='B';
CREATE EDGE OwnedBy FROM (Select from FacebookAccount where user='B_FB') TO (Select from Human where person='B');
CREATE EDGE OwnedBy FROM (Select from TwitterAccount where user='B_TW') TO (Select from Human where person='B');

/* C */
create VERTEX FacebookAccount set user='C_FB';
create VERTEX TwitterAccount set user='C_TW';
create VERTEX Human set person='C';
CREATE EDGE OwnedBy FROM (Select from FacebookAccount where user='C_FB') TO (Select from Human where person='C');
CREATE EDGE OwnedBy FROM (Select from TwitterAccount where user='C_TW') TO (Select from Human where person='C');

/* X */
create VERTEX Human set person='X';
create VERTEX FacebookAccount set user='X_FB';
CREATE EDGE OwnedBy FROM (Select from FacebookAccount where user='X_FB') TO (Select from Human where person='X');

/* Y */
create VERTEX FacebookAccount set user='Y_FB';


CREATE EDGE FriendOf FROM (Select from FacebookAccount where user='Y_FB') TO (Select from FacebookAccount where user='X_FB');
CREATE EDGE FriendOf FROM (Select from FacebookAccount where user='X_FB') TO (Select from FacebookAccount where user='C_FB');
CREATE EDGE FriendOf FROM (Select from FacebookAccount where user='A_FB') TO (Select from FacebookAccount where user='B_FB');
CREATE EDGE FriendOf FROM (Select from FacebookAccount where user='B_FB') TO (Select from FacebookAccount where user='C_FB');
```

Comment: It seems like you may want to prevent any accounts from being owned by no one. OwnedBy may be better as a link than an edge so you can make it mandatory (and also enforce only one owner per account). Also, if user and OwnedBy are always the same, then you could combine them into one link.